# ubuntu groups not returning all my groups

Tags: ubuntu

when I run groups in ubuntu without my username

```
 delliott@delliott:/var/www$ groups
 delliott wheel
```

it returns two groups I'm in.

when I do

```
 delliott@delliott:/var/www$ groups delliott
 delliott : delliott wheel webusers
```

it returns all three groups I'm in

when I run

```
 delliott@delliott:/var/www$ whoami
```

it returns

```
 delliott
```

which I expect

and when I run

```
 delliott@delliott:/var/www$ id delliott
```

it returns

```
 uid=1006(delliott) gid=1007(delliott) groups=1007(delliott),1001(wheel),1010(webusers)
```

why doesn't it list all three when I just do groups with no username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group membership is updated at login time. Maybe one of your shells was opened before making the corresponding changes to groups and hasn't properly reloaded yet. Specifically, the deliott session in the first example appears to be outdated (you added your user to the "webusers" group and have not reloaded the session since).